# Python Time differencing in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Lets say I have an array of date:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date': [ '5/4/1985', '6/13/1983', '6/13/1982', '12/28/1987'], 'Name': ['J','K','L','M']})
```

and I want to find the difference between them and today in years, weeks, or quarters (four in one year).

So far I know I would use `pd.datetime.now()` to represent today.

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of nano second difference, Just do:

```
In [60]:
pd.datetime.now()-pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
Out[60]:
0   10508 days, 15:56:08.609000
1   11199 days, 15:56:08.609000
2   11564 days, 15:56:08.609000
3    9540 days, 15:56:08.609000
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

To get the difference in days or years (etc):

```
q=pd.datetime.now()-pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
array(q).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int) #in days
array(q).astype('timedelta64[Y]').astype(int) #in years
```

Comment: is there a way to get years, quarters or weeks instead of days

Comment: Sorry, the default is not in days but in nanoseconds. Corrected that. I don't know if you can get quarters, there are 4 types available for `timedelta64`: `D W M Y`, for day, week, month and year respectively.

Comment: So I guess the only way to change it to quarters is to change to months then divide by 3?

Comment: I guess that will be better (than calculated it from the number of weeks or days). There may be more elegant way of doing it, I don't know.